# Background service/application on windows platform (Windows App SDK)

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, maui, maui-windows

I wanna make application for windows using .net maui with basic service such as counter which can be still running after I quit application - something similar to foreground service on android. I try to use background task from uwp but it doesnt`t work, and I don`t know it is correct way to make this app?
I base my app using this guideline:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/guidelines-for-background-tasks

```
{
    public sealed class DemoService : IBackgroundTask,IBackgroundService
    {
        private BackgroundTaskDeferral backgroundTaskDeferral;


        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            // Get a deferral so that the service isn't terminated.
            backgroundTaskDeferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

            // Associate a cancellation handler with the background task.
       
            taskInstance.Canceled += OnCanceled;
        }


        private void OnCanceled(IBackgroundTaskInstance sender, BackgroundTaskCancellationReason reason)
        {
            //
            // Indicate that the background task is canceled.
            //

            if (this.backgroundTaskDeferral != null)
            {
                // Complete the service deferral.
                this.backgroundTaskDeferral.Complete();
            }
        }



         
        public void RegisterBackgroundTask() 
        {




        }

        public void UnRegisterBackgroundTask()
        {
            foreach (var cur in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
            {
              cur.Value.Unregister(true);              
            }
        }


        public static BackgroundTaskRegistration RegisterBackgroundTask(string taskEntryPoint,
                                                                  string taskName,
                                                                  IBackgroundTrigger trigger,
                                                                  IBackgroundCondition condition)
        {
            // Check for existing registrations of this background task.

            foreach (var cur in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
            {

                if (cur.Value.Name == taskName)
                {
                    // The task is already registered.

                    return (BackgroundTaskRegistration)(cur.Value);
                }
            }


            //
            // Register the background task.
            //

            var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

            builder.Name = taskName;
            builder.TaskEntryPoint = taskEntryPoint;
            builder.SetTrigger(trigger);

            if (condition != null)
            {

                builder.AddCondition(condition);
            }

            BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();

            return task;
        }
    }
```

```
using System.Diagnostics.Metrics;
using System.Reflection;


namespace BackgroundServiceUWP;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private bool isRunning;
    private int count = 0;
    public readonly IBackgroundService service;


    public MainPage(IBackgroundService service)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.service = service;
    }

    private async void RunBackgroundTask(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //start service
        service.RegisterBackgroundTask();

        isRunning = true;

        while (isRunning)
        {
            count++;
            Counter.Text = count.ToString();
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
        }

    }

    private void StopBackgroundTask(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isRunning = false;
        count = 0;
        Counter.Text = count.ToString();
        //stop service
        service.UnRegisterBackgroundTask();
    }


}
```

```
        <Label`enter code here`
            x:Name="Counter"
            FontSize="18"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Button
            Text="Start Service"
            Clicked="RunBackgroundTask"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />


        <Button
            Text="Stop Service"
            Clicked="StopBackgroundTask"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

```
namespace BackgroundServiceUWP
{
    public interface IBackgroundService
    {
        void RegisterBackgroundTask();

        void UnRegisterBackgroundTask();

    }
}
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a helpful description of the problem.  Please show us what you've tried and the specific errors or problems you're having

Comment: "background tasks" are a UWP feature. My understanding is that the doc you linked uses a UWP-specific API. On Windows, Maui runs on WinUI 3, which is part of Windows App SDK. I'm not finding any equivalent in App SDK to UWP background tasks. Not sure what is recommended. Need a Microsoft Windows App expert (not a Maui expert).

Comment: I try to make simple counter background application using .net maui which I can run on windows but I don`t find anything like that in .net maui so I try  use background task from uwp

Answer (score 0):

There is an existed issue about the [Service/Background Task in the .net maui](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9598) on the github.

And according to the comment in it, this is the limit in the WinUI, you can report it to the WinUI 3 on the github.

In addition, you can check this discussion about [Windows App SDK need better support for periodic background tasks](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/discussions/2322). There is a workaround about [Timer-triggered background task in the WinUI](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/discussions/2314) in it.